# Why do template template parameters with constraints require stricter arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++14

[N3580](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) describes the following scenario:

```
template<Object T, template<Object> Cont>
struct stack {
    Cont<T> container;
};

template<Object>
struct my_vector;

template<Regular>
struct my_list;

template<typename>
struct my_magic;
```

Here, `Regular` is a refinement of `Object`; that is, every `Regular` is an
`Object` but not every `Object` is a `Regular`.

I would expect the type system to be such that for `stack<X, Y>` to be valid,
`X` must be an `Object` and `Y` must be instantiable with an `Object`.  This
would mean that `stack<int, my_vector>` and `stack<int, my_magic>` are valid,
while `stack<int, my_list>` is not.  Much like the case with normal functions:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

void foo(Base* p, function<void(Base*)> fun) {
    fun(p);
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T*);
```

I would expect that if `p` is a `Base*`, then `foo(p, bar<Base>)` and `foo(p,
bar<void>)` are valid, while `foo(p, bar<Derived>)` is not; after all, a
`Base*` has an implicit conversion to a `void*`, but not to a `Derived*`.

In the case of templates, though, the situation is the opposite.  Only
`stack<int, my_vector>` and `stack<int, my_list>` are allowed, while `stack<int,
my_magic>` is forbidden.  Why is this?  `my_magic` works fine with any type,
while `my_list` may fail depending on what object I give it.  Moreover, I can
trivially make `my_magic` work with only objects:

```
template<Object T>
struct my_restricted_magic : my_magic<T> {};
```

Now `my_restricted_magic` can be used with `stack`.  On the other hand, there's
no easy way of making a `my_list` which accepts any type, but this is exactly
what passing it as a template template parameter now allows.

Am I misinterpreting the purpose of constraints on template template parameter's
parameters?

Comment: @KerrekSB N3580 is a C++1y paper.  `Bar` has one type argument constrained by the concept `Object`.

Comment: @Yakk: Oh, I see. I actually read that once. (It's not *in* C++1y though, is it?)

Comment: @KerrekSB Nope, it'll be a separate TS.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. Do you think your last line should be allowed? Why?

Comment: @sftrabbit: I expect passing template templates to work much like passing functions, while it actually does the opposite.  Basically, I'd expect contravariance, but get covariance instead.

Comment: Maybe as the designer of `MyStruct`, you should be able to rely on the instantiation of `Bar` *failing* for something that doesn't fulfil the `Object` constraints. Otherwise, you could instantiate it but get the usual error messages from using this instantiation.

Comment: Note that if there were *no* restriction on constraints of the template template-parameter's template-parameters, you'd still get nice error message during instantiation if the supplied template's template-parameter is more constrained: E.g. `template< template<Object> class Bar > struct MyStruct { Bar<some_non_object_type> x; /* fails */ };` OTOH, if it is less constrained, then this instantiation doesn't fail.

Comment: @DyP: Hmm, that's a good point, actually.  On the other hand, the instantiation of `Bar` seems like an implementation detail to me; I'd rather it fail earlier than later.

Comment: I totally agree with you now and [I've emailed the SG8 mailing list about it](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/concepts/aypsd7S2C3s).

Comment: Ah, that does seem like the better place to ask.  [I've emailed std-discussion.](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/Cofx3ctEsiM)

Comment: Have a read of [the latest draft proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3819.pdf), section 4.3.1. Although it's terribly written (where the hell does `Q` come from? should be `P`?), from what I can tell, the text says what you think it should be and the example disagrees with it.

Comment: Ideally both contravariance and covariance would be possible, at least with a `requires` clause.  Are both possible under the text as written?  If they reverse the rule?

Comment: "Good" news. It looks like it's [a bug with the spec](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/concepts/aypsd7S2C3s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in the proposal. A constrained template template parameter should accept arguments with weaker constraints.

Comment: Thanks!  Is the current behaviour ([allowed](http://ideone.com/pknN7a), [forbidden](http://ideone.com/LtnXoS)) also backwards?

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't have a good answer. It looks like you can make a very convincing argument that [allowed] should be an error, and [forbidden] should be valid. The reasoning would follow the arguments here: that the template template parameter's signature announces the intended use of the argument.

Comment: Ugh. Stupid comment editing system.

The reason being that the template template parameter's signature expresses the intended use of the argument, and the arguments provided don't support the intended uses.

Right or wrong, the standard requires that behavior (14.3.3/3). Maybe a defect report is in order.

Comment: Hm, this seems to have been introduced by N2555, where such matching rules were desired for the implementation of Boost's MPL and Proto libraries.  It seems like people want a way of taking a template that "can be anything", and which they simply want to instantiate with a user-provided parameter pack.  This doesn't go well with the meta-type-safety that constraints want to add, but it does look like a valid use case.  Thanks, I'll look into submitting a defect report.  (I think the [forbidden] case should definitely be allowed.)

Comment: @AntonGolov Note that we don't have "anything", as a `template` that takes a mixture of types and values cannot be taken, and you cannot have a pack of a mixture of types and values.  Here is a way to map your `typename...` to a unary template: http://ideone.com/3wX9o5 -- if allowed/forbidden was reversed, I don't think I could write such an adapter the other way.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, the reason it first bugged me is that there's a natural conversion one way but not the other, and the standard only allows an implicit conversion the way there's no natural one.  Forbidding the one that's allowed is not an option, but I'm wondering if template parameters need some kind of "early-checked" vs "late-checked" tag.  I'm working on an email to std-discussion about this.

Answer (score 1):

This is conjecture, but it seems like a likely explanation:

Allowing to pass a more specific template, rather than a more generic one, is the way the rules currently work in regard to variadic template template parameters.  You are allowed to pass a single-type-parameter template where a variadic is expected:

```
template<template<typename...> class> struct Foo {};
template<typename> Bar {};

Foo<Bar>(); // legal
```

But not vice-versa:

```
template<template<typename> class> struct Foo {};
template<typename...> Bar {};

Foo<Bar>(); // error, argument/parameter mismatch.
```

The phrasing originated in N2555 where it was requested to allow code like this:

```
template<typename>
struct Foo;

template<template<typename...> class Fun, template... Args>
struct Foo<Fun<Args...>> {};

Foo<std::pair<int, double>>();
```

Basically, instead of the `template<typename...> class` being a guarantee to the user, it is a catch-all thing that the user must then provide sensible arguments for.  Given this usage involving specialisations, that does seem reasonable.

This does not explain why passing a more general template is not allowed, but reversing the phrasing in N3580 would make the two rules put together rather unintuitive.

Proposal link: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2555.pdf‎